# Redirect or render to detect this Rails flash?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, flash

On my Rails site when the user adds a product through a form I need to take them to the page for the product and show a flash (the flash will be blank) that I'll be able to detect in my JavaScript; I'm using a custom flash that I set in application.html.erb. I'm not sure if I need to use a redirect or render for this. Here's my create action (doesn't work):

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.set_user!(current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
                if !current_user.braintree_customer_id?
                    flash.now[:addmethod] = ""
                    format.html {render :action => "show"}
                else
                    format.html {render :action => "show"}
                end
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Woops, looks like something went wrong."
        format.html {render :action => "create"}
      end
    end

end
```

So what do I need to use? Render or redirect?

Comment: you should `redirect` to `show` action.

Comment: @RAJ... `new` I believe?

Comment: @nithin Let me re-phrase, he should redirect control to show action after creating record in create action.

Comment: @RAJ... right. I was taking on `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect to `show` action after successfully creating the `product` and in case of error, you need to render `new`.

You can update your `create` action as:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.set_user!(current_user)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
      flash.now[:addmethod] = "" unless current_user.braintree_customer_id?
      format.html { redirect_to @product }
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Woops, looks like something went wrong."
      format.html { render "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Your Show action must be looks like:

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  ... # other code, if you need

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

minor tidy - to make it easier to read I used the answer section (despite the fact its not an answer !)

```
if @product.save
  if !current_user.braintree_customer_id?
    flash.now[:addmethod] = ""
  end
  format.html {render :action => "show"}
else
  flash.now[:alert] = "Woops, looks like something went wrong."
  format.html {render :action => "create"}
```